# Pause on one of branches in DirectShow graph

Tags: directshow

I wrote an app for video capture. That app uses the following graph:
[image]

As you see after Smart Tee it has two banches. The first,  "Capture",  I use for stream handling, the second, "Preview", for show of video on the app's window. 
Sometimes an user minimizes that window and using  Preview branch is not need. For that case I would like to stop a stream only on this branch.

I can do it by stop and rebuild of all graph without Preview. But I would like don't to stop/rebuild the graph. Perhaps, does somebody  knows the other method to do it? Any ideas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a preview stream to the graph without stopping it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069432/how-can-i-add-a-preview-stream-to-the-graph-without-stopping-it)

Comment: Thank you for info.  But I try to build the graph with one branch and lock a VMR stream into the grabber. The grabber is my own filter and I have a full control on it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to just stop a part of a graph. For such a scenario you need multiple graphs (source, grabber, preview) and the [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/).

By the way, why do you need the tee? Can't you connect the video-renderer to the grabber?

Comment: You are right, I will do it in the grabber branch without the tee . Thank you